# How to pass data from one view to another when I use SideMenu

Tags: swift3.2

I have a side menu. In my Home screen, I am getting data. but when I select the side menu and again opening Home screen.I lost my data in Home Screen.I am using viewwillapper method but it doesn't work.Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: pls share any suggestions to my issue

Comment: need more explanation.. share the code u r using

Comment: actually passing data from one view to another view is simple. But How to Pass data between side menu screens.